# How to remove default tag and category options form a custom post type admin menu

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

In my theme I have added a custom post type and in the admin side the new CPT menu shows default categories and tags above the new CPT categories and tags.

Question how do I get rid of the default category & tag menu items?

[image]

Ideally I'd just like it to be:

- All Photography Posts
- Add New
- Photography Categories
- Photography Tags

I used this code and changed "Custom" to "Photography".

```
    <?php
    /* Bones Custom Post Type Example
    This page walks you through creating 
    a custom post type and taxonomies. You
    can edit this one or copy the following code 
    to create another one. 

    I put this in a separate file so as to 
    keep it organized. I find it easier to edit
    and change things if they are concentrated
    in their own file.

    Developed by: Eddie Machado
    URL: http://themble.com/bones/
    */

    // Flush rewrite rules for custom post types
    add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'bones_flush_rewrite_rules' );

    // Flush your rewrite rules
    function bones_flush_rewrite_rules() {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    // let's create the function for the custom type
    function custom_post_example() { 
        // creating (registering) the custom type 
        register_post_type( 'custom_type', /* (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) */
            // let's now add all the options for this post type
            array( 'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Custom Types', 'bonestheme' ), /* This is the Title of the Group */
                'singular_name' => __( 'Custom Post', 'bonestheme' ), /* This is the individual type */
                'all_items' => __( 'All Custom Posts', 'bonestheme' ), /* the all items menu item */
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'bonestheme' ), /* The add new menu item */
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Custom Type', 'bonestheme' ), /* Add New Display Title */
                'edit' => __( 'Edit', 'bonestheme' ), /* Edit Dialog */
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Post Types', 'bonestheme' ), /* Edit Display Title */
                'new_item' => __( 'New Post Type', 'bonestheme' ), /* New Display Title */
                'view_item' => __( 'View Post Type', 'bonestheme' ), /* View Display Title */
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Post Type', 'bonestheme' ), /* Search Custom Type Title */ 
                'not_found' =>  __( 'Nothing found in the Database.', 'bonestheme' ), /* This displays if there are no entries yet */ 
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nothing found in Trash', 'bonestheme' ), /* This displays if there is nothing in the trash */
                'parent_item_colon' => ''
                ), /* end of arrays */
                'description' => __( 'This is the example custom post type', 'bonestheme' ), /* Custom Type Description */
                'public' => true,
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'exclude_from_search' => false,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'menu_position' => 8, /* this is what order you want it to appear in on the left hand side menu */ 
                'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/images/custom-post-icon.png', /* the icon for the custom post type menu */
                'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'custom_type', 'with_front' => false ), /* you can specify its url slug */
                'has_archive' => 'custom_type', /* you can rename the slug here */
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'hierarchical' => false,
                /* the next one is important, it tells what's enabled in the post editor */
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'sticky')
            ) /* end of options */
        ); /* end of register post type */

        /* this adds your post categories to your custom post type */
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'custom_type' );
        /* this adds your post tags to your custom post type */
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'custom_type' );

    }

        // adding the function to the Wordpress init
        add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_example');

        /*
        for more information on taxonomies, go here:
        http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy
        */

        // now let's add custom categories (these act like categories)
        register_taxonomy( 'custom_cat', 
            array('custom_type'), /* if you change the name of register_post_type( 'custom_type', then you have to change this */
            array('hierarchical' => true,     /* if this is true, it acts like categories */
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Custom Categories', 'bonestheme' ), /* name of the custom taxonomy */
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Custom Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* single taxonomy name */
                    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Custom Categories', 'bonestheme' ), /* search title for taxomony */
                    'all_items' => __( 'All Custom Categories', 'bonestheme' ), /* all title for taxonomies */
                    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Custom Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* parent title for taxonomy */
                    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Custom Category:', 'bonestheme' ), /* parent taxonomy title */
                    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Custom Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* edit custom taxonomy title */
                    'update_item' => __( 'Update Custom Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* update title for taxonomy */
                    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Custom Category', 'bonestheme' ), /* add new title for taxonomy */
                    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Custom Category Name', 'bonestheme' ) /* name title for taxonomy */
                ),
                'show_admin_column' => true, 
                'show_ui' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'custom-slug' ),
            )
        );

        // now let's add custom tags (these act like categories)
        register_taxonomy( 'custom_tag', 
            array('custom_type'), /* if you change the name of register_post_type( 'custom_type', then you have to change this */
            array('hierarchical' => false,    /* if this is false, it acts like tags */
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Custom Tags', 'bonestheme' ), /* name of the custom taxonomy */
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Custom Tag', 'bonestheme' ), /* single taxonomy name */
                    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Custom Tags', 'bonestheme' ), /* search title for taxomony */
                    'all_items' => __( 'All Custom Tags', 'bonestheme' ), /* all title for taxonomies */
                    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Custom Tag', 'bonestheme' ), /* parent title for taxonomy */
                    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Custom Tag:', 'bonestheme' ), /* parent taxonomy title */
                    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Custom Tag', 'bonestheme' ), /* edit custom taxonomy title */
                    'update_item' => __( 'Update Custom Tag', 'bonestheme' ), /* update title for taxonomy */
                    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Custom Tag', 'bonestheme' ), /* add new title for taxonomy */
                    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Custom Tag Name', 'bonestheme' ) /* name title for taxonomy */
                ),
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
            )
        );

        /*
            looking for custom meta boxes?
            check out this fantastic tool:
            https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress
        */


    ?>
```

Comment: With code, I used the Bones theme as a template to build from.

Comment: how do you create the CPT ? edit your question to show the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove these lines:

```
/* this adds your post categories to your custom post type */
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'custom_type' );
/* this adds your post tags to your custom post type */
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'custom_type' );
```

They're adding tags and categories to your post type, so of course they're appearing.

Comment: Ah, I though they added the CPT tags and categories, d'oh! Thanks.